# How do I customize the MUI DataGrid footer components?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

I am using the MUI V5 DataGrid component in my App and I want to customize the Footer component on the datagrid component but can't find any docs on how to go about it. This is the current default footer:
[image: Data Grid Footer]

I want to achieve something resembling this:[image: Custom Footer]

Is there a way to reorganize the individual components and customize the styling as such? Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

this sample code you can use for a custom footer in data grid MUI v5

first, you write your pagination component with full logic when the client clicked on the page, like this :

```
    const RoundedPagination = () => {
    return (
        <Stack spacing={2}>
            <Pagination
                shape="rounded" page={page + 1} onChange={handleChange} count={props.numberOfPages}
                renderItem={(item) => (
                    <PaginationItem
                        sx={{
                            color: 'main.0',
                        }}
                        components={{previous: ArrowRightRoundedIcon, next: ArrowLeftRoundedIcon}}
                        {...item}
                    />
                )}
            />
        </Stack>
    )
}
```

then you use this component in data grid like this :

```
            <Grid container item justifyContent={'center'} alignItems={'center'} md={12}>
            <DataGrid
                page={page}
                rows={props.dataGridValue.ROW}
                columns={props.dataGridValue.COLUMNS}
                autoHeight
                headerHeight={52}
                rowsPerPageOptions={[10]}
                disableColumnMenu
                Pagination
                hideFooterSelectedRowCount
                components={{
                    Pagination: RoundedPagination,
                }}
            />
        </Grid>
```

hope you get your answer good luck ;)